# .Net Core 3.1 How do I import a .cert and .key file in a X509Certificate2 Object?

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate, private-key

This is the first time I am dealing in code with certificates.

My problem is, that I need to sign emails with a certificate that is split in a .cert and in a .key file. Those files need to be read from the file system and cannot be stored in some kind certificate store.

The self signed private key for testing purposes starts like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,B5F1CE2CAB1B3CE20326EF3CD60D230

tmPJKtI8S4dGl2B29HhyHlF6Dp6/mDldldX/n2+gYvfSaa4TEPVFQMJfLsRxp1ey
...
```

Importing the .cert part is fairly easy and straight forward:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(_emailConfig.PathToCertificate);
```

But I fail to figure out how to add the private key which I need for the actual signing.

This needs to also work on Linux.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 0:**

I obtained a string called privateKey that only contains the private key without any PEM syntax.

Then I did the following:

```
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
using var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);
```

Then I assigned the key:

```
certificate.PrivateKey = rsa;
```

The problem is I am getting the following Exception: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : ASN1 corrupted data.`

Comment: .NET's built-in crypto stack gained support for reading key files in .NET Core 3.0... but it can't read files using the PEM attributes syntax (e.g. "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED").

Comment: Thanks. I will just remove the PEM syntax and give it a shot.

Comment: Well. I managed to remove the superflux syntax  and managed to get the actual key with var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
            using var rsa = RSA.Create();
            rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);